# Check Logged in User inside Firebase functions (Not inside Flutter or web)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know the following

1. How to get the Logged in User id inside firebase functions
2. How to check a custom claim inside a firebase function

I know, we can check the auth inside callable function, but how about https functions

A help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For `https` functions, you'll have to explicitly pass user's ID Token in your HTTP request (e.g. in `Authorization` header). Then you can [verify that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) which returns a [DecodedIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken) object that contains user's custom claims.

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on how to retrieve user's ID Token and for more information.

Comment: Isnt there a way to get something like - ****.getCurrentUser().
I mean we have the same inside the flutter firebase sdk

Comment: @Dhrubajyoti no, you'll have to manually verify the token. You can find any pre-made middleware node package if any